# jQuery Toggle not working using this.name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've created a contact form with validation and was trying to bolt on a help function whereby someone clicks on the question mark and a div with the explanation pops up.

I found a way to do it using a variable and "this" selector which seemed to work fine but it's  stopped working and I can't seem to prevent the default # behaviour.

Having looked at similar questions, nothing has indicated what the problem might be. Here is the function:

```
$(function() {
    //show/hide
    $('a.form-question-help-link').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var divname= this.name;
        $("#"+divname).toggle();
        return false;
});

});
```

jsFiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/dvmac/dpVzL/2/

Comment: Give `$(this).prop('name')` a shot.

Comment: Try `console.log(this.name)` and see if you are really getting the div id as expected or not

Comment: The fiddle is working for me? What's the issue?

Comment: @undefined $(this) returns a collection (in this case 1 element), this returns the element alone, prop selects the property name and gives you it's value.

Comment: @PatsyIssa which is same as `this.name` which gets the property `name` from teh dom reference

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yup but for the sake of already using jquery and pretty code.

Comment: the only question is whether the the elements are created dynamically... might be those elements are created using a script or using ajax loading???

Comment: @PatsyIssa but it is nice and less and....

Comment: I'll take a wild guess and suggest you to try event delegation like `$(document).on('click', 'a.form-question-help-link', function(event) {...});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny +1 on the dynamically added elements. P.s: i like the $ syntax :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$(this).attr('name')` or `$(this).prop('name')`.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/txqNA/) fiddle.

Comment: which is the same thing as `this.name`

Comment: I tried this and it works great on the fiddle but when I'm implementing it on my page it doesn't work. Here is the form page:http://www.trustedheatingsuppliers.co.uk/index.php?action=eco_funding&src=#

Comment: How would this make any difference!?

Answer (score 1):

The `#` selector selects based off of id.  If you want to select off of name, you need the attribute slector: `'[name="' + divname + '"]'`

```
$('a.form-question-help-link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var divname= this.name;
    $('[name="' + divname + '"]').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

An even better way is to just to do this: `$(this)`

```
$('a.form-question-help-link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

And if you have dynamically created elements, then you may want to try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.form-question-help-link', function(e) {
    $(this).toggle();        
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
should be $(this) instead of this

$(function() {
        //show/hide
        $('a.form-question-help-link').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var divname= $(this).name;
            $("#"+divname).toggle();
            return false;
    });

    });
```

Comment: There is no `.name` in jQuery